# Calling a Future Function from another screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hyperlink, call, future

I have a Future Function in **popup.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';

void main() {
  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new Popup(),
    ));
}

class Popup extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PopupState createState() => _PopupState();
}

enum Answers{TEAMA,TEAMB}

class _PopupState extends State<Popup> {

  String _value = '';

  void _setValue(String value) => setState(() => _value = value);

Future _askUser() async {
        switch(
        await showDialog(
          context: context,
          child: new SimpleDialog(
            title: new Text('SELECT YOUR TEAM',
            ),
```

And I have **pages/pageone.dart**, which I would like to call "**_askUser**" to onTap.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:myapp/popup.dart';

....

     GestureDetector(
        onTap: _askUser,
        child: Container(
          child: ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
            child: Image.asset('assets/PLUS.png',
              scale: 8),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

I am getting error "Undefined name '_askUser'."

How to call the _askUser?

In popup.dart, everything works but I cannot access the same popup link in pageone.dart

Thank you in advance!

Comment: _askUser is a top level function?

Comment: If I understand correctly, top level function is "Popup" which is a StatefulWidget.

Comment: I don't see any Popup widget... maybe you should share the full code

Comment: I have edited the question. I am looking forward to hearing from you! Thanks!

Comment: Are you using somewhere the Popup widget? also have you defined a build function for it? Btw `_askUser`  is not a top level function but a method of the `_PopupState` classe, which since it's private can be called only within the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the best implementation of this is by declaring everything you need about the user in a user_service.dart file. There, you create a class like

```
class UserService {
  var playerTeam; // just for example
  askUser() {} // the underscore in everything indicates it is private. 
}
```

make your askUser change "playerTeam", and when you need to call it, use

```
UserService userService = UserService();
userService.askUser();
```

And I'm not sure about your code, but making a singleton of UserService could help a lot since it will have only one instance

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried what you said but I could not do that. Could you please give me more explaination? For example, what should I type onTap class?